# How do I find what font Chrome is using to display non-latin script?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, fonts, language, chinese

I'm doing some coding that involves displaying Chinese characters as images, and observed that the font I'm using for coding (simsun) does not display a lot of the characters that my browser displays fine.

E.g. all the characters on [this page](http://hanzidb.org/character-list?page=749) appear fine in my browser, but do not display in simsun. When I view the source code of the page, the font is "Helvetica Neue,... sans-serif", which suggests the browser is just defaulting to its sans-serif font.

But I have no idea how to view my browser (Chrome)'s default Chinese fonts.

Comment: Firefox displays "MingLiU_HKSCS-ExtB". Maybe Chrome hast a similar mechanism in its developer tools. // I’ll edit the title to be a little more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using in Chrome the extension
[Font Finder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/font-finder/bhiichidigehdgphoambhjbekalahgha?hl=en)
gave this information:

---

[image]

---

The answer to your question is then that the font being used in Chrome is `NSimSun`.
I don't know if this is the same as your font `simsun`.

Comment: Thanks. I find this very weird, as it seems that `simsun` includes the NSimSun font, yet doesn't render all the characters my browser can. I've posted the full issue [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/138464/trying-to-understand-how-fonts-work), if you know what's going on.